# Crop Bitmap from center to fit display width and height

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-bitmap

[How can i make bitmap to fit to display height and width of display from the center of the bitmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9ug3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Click the `scaleType` dropdown in the attributes column at the right of the screen (it looks like the image below) and select `fitXY`.

[image]

Comment: The thing is the bitmap is loaded from url and is used to set as wallpaper .so each image has different dimension.I need a uniform crop of any bitmap to fit the screen size from the image center.